# Datatable Filter Server Side Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, datatable

I have table filter with datatable, but why the filter won't return all data from datatable?

complete jquery:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    //table definition
    var table = $('#tbl').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        "filter": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": '/member/serverSide/',
            "type": "GET"
        },

        //get data from ajax
        columns: [
            { data: 'Expedisi', name: 'Expedisi', "dropdown" : true},
            { data: 'Type', name: 'Type' },
            { data: 'Moda', name: 'Moda' },
            { data: 'Asal', name: 'Asal' },
            { data: 'Tujuan', name: 'Tujuan' },
            { data: 'ETD', name: 'ETD' },
            { data: 'Weight', name: 'Weight' },
            { data: 'Price', name: 'Price' },
            { data: 'Minimal', name: 'Minimal' },
            { data: 'Price Minimal', name: 'Price Minimal' },
            { data: 'Price Per Point', name: 'Price Per Point' },
            { data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false}
        ],

        initComplete......,

        "order": [[ 4, "asc" ], [ 10, "asc" ]],
        "columnDefs": [{
                "targets": [ 0,4,10 ], //first column / numbering column
                "orderable": true, //set not orderable
            },
        ]
    });
});
```

here is my Jquery code for create filter:

```
initComplete: function () {
    this.api().columns([0]).every(function () {
        var column = this;
        var select = $('#xped').appendTo($('#tabel')).on( 'change', function () {
            var val = $(this).val();
            column.search( this.value ).draw();
        });

        column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
            select.append( '<option>'+d+'</option>' )
        });
    });
}
```

and here is screenshot of my table view:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpDrg.png)

Comment: There is no such `filter` option in DataTable. [`filter() api`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/filter()) is there.

Comment: I can see the two values are there in the dropdown. What else you want?

Comment: @PrashantPokhriyal how and where to add that filter.api() in my code ?? any reference??

Comment: @CodeThing that is just two values from all Expedisi's datas